# NUnit Command line Switch /include: execution order

Tags: testing, nunit, nunit-console

I run nunit-console using the following command line:

```
nunit-console-x86.exe IntegrationTests.dll /include:InstallerTests,SanityTests,DebuggingTests /xml=IntegrationTestResults.xml /nologo /labels /timeout:960000
```

My issue is that the test runs in alphabetic order.  Is there any way to force NUnit to run the tests based on category order we mention in command line `/include` switch? I would like to run Installer tests first then Sanity and finally Debugging tests.

One partial solution is to run individual categories separately but I want the test results in single XML file so that it is easy to manipulate results.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No, there isn't currently a way to get nunit-console to do what you are asking.

Generally, unit-tests (which is the primary target audience for nunit) are written such that order of execution doesn't matter.  Given that, it seems unlikely that adding order based execution to nunit-console is likely to be a change that's likely to arrive any time soon.

Post-processing the result file is going to be the easiest option.

There are however other approaches that can be used to control the order of execution.  For example [this one](https://www.ingenuityworking.com/knowledge/w/knowledgebase/1354.nunit-sequencer-tool-to-sequence-run-ordered-nunit-tests-and-fixtures-by-setting-attributes.aspx) takes advantage of the fact that NUnit executes tests in alphabetical order to arrange tests before execution.